Why won’t my rear hub motor spin?
So I have an electric bike my old motor was throwing e-07 code so I ended up getting a new motor I installed it and at first the tire would spin counter clockwise which is supposed to be clockwise and now it won’t spin at all . But the motor turns on tries to work, no error codes not sure if it could have something to do with my hub axle washers and nuts or maybe the brake I had the brake caliper off maybe I put it in wrong but not sure what else to do I’d rather not take the motor apart if it’s a problem I can fix easy

A 3 phase motor will spin the other way if you swap any two phase wires over.

See my controller had 9 wires this hub I just bought only has 8 I spliced them together dude told me I didn’t need the white wire does that matter ?

Please add more info into your question with [edit].   8 vs 9 wires would be important info.
